# Export path in bash file

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a Matlab code in the HPC of my university. The code is submitted using `qsub` and a `bash` file.

In order to use Matlab R2019b, I have been instructed that: *To make use of Matlab R2019b add the following to the top of your script after the scheduler flags*

```
export PATH=/username/local/matlab/bin:$PATH
```

I'm having troubles in doing that. At the moment, my bash file opens Matlab R2015b (instead of Matlab R2019b). (Note: in place of username I have put my actual username). This is my bash:

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=4G
#$ -l tmem=4G
#$ -l h_rt=24:0:0
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y

#Run 3 tasks where each task has a different $SGE_TASK_ID ranging from 1 to 3
#$ -t 1-3

#$ -N try
date
hostname


#Output the Task ID
echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

export PATH=/username/local/matlab/bin:$PATH


matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main_1; ID = $SGE_TASK_ID; main_2; exit"
```

I have also tried with `export PATH=/username/local/matlabR2019b/bin:$PATH` but the issue persists.

Also, if from the terminal I type `cd /home/username/local` it tells me that the folder does not exist. How is that possible?

Comment: Where is Matlab actually installed in? It's impossible to help you without this info. Also for some reasons I believe it must be `$HOME/local/matlab/bin:$PATH`, and not what is proposed.

Comment: The instructions say (exact quoting): "Matlab 2019b is installed locally on the compute nodes rather than in share apps.  To make use of it add the following to the top of your script after the scheduler flags export PATH=/username/local/matlab/bin:$PATH"

Comment: In short please show the output of 

`find / -name matlab -xdev 2>/dev/null`. If it returns nothing remove `-xdev`

Comment: Add the output of `which matlab` to your question. I'm pretty sure that it's not installed in `/username/local/matlab`.

Comment: @NasirRiley: sorry, I did not get it: where should I add exactly `which matlab`?

Comment: Also, if I type `cd /home/username/local` in the terminal, it tells me that the folder does not exist. How is that possible?

Comment: Please run the command I've given earlier. Don't be annoying and inattentive.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: thanks, it's still running. It is producing a long list of paths.

Comment: OK, then change it to `find / -name matlab -type f -xdev 2>/dev/null` and run it again. **Post the output in your question**, not in a comment.

Comment: `find / -name matlab -type f -xdev 2>/dev/null` produces nothing. I'm now running `find / -name matlab -type f 2>/dev/null` but for the moment it is not giving anything yet.

Comment: It may take a lot of time. Please wait.

Comment: Run the commands `which matlab` and `whereis matlab` in the terminal and add the output to your question.

Comment: don't bite, have you actually installed matlab yourself? only adding a path is not sufficient. and */username* is not */home/username*

Answer (score 1):

To locate which matlab is being used by the script, at the command line, try

```
PATH="/username/local/matlab/bin:$PATH"   ; export PATH
```

The quotes guarantee correct assignment of path if there are space characters in the directory tree to the command.  Then enter

```
which matlab
```

that will give you the fullpath to the matlab command, which should give you insights as to what is getting precedence and why.  Sometimes, the output of

```
whereis matlab
```

will give you other hints to help solve the PATH precedence issue.

If you have more than one installation of matlab, you may need to purge the offending one.

If you have only one installation of matlab, you need to do a complete package removal (including config files) using whichever tool you prefer, then re-install the package.  You might be suffering from some old config values applicable to earlier versions.